# How do I resolve the node sass install error

Tags: node.js, angular, node-gyp, node-sass

```
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.3.0
```

npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

Comment: Give more information with your question, like some relevance, people here don't remember errors and what they mean by heart. Add code and steps to reproduce this exact error. Here is a [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command:

```
npm install -g sass --save
```

Comment: Please upvote the answer if it helped. It will help others too in the future. Thank you.